# Deadlock between different event threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, awt

I'd always worked in java with the understanding that if I farmed off a task to the event thread, it could use any suitiable locks it needed and it would never bump into with any other locks I made from the event thread.

Unfortunately, my webstart program has three event threads, and two of them are deadlocking.

I have AWT-EventQueue-0 in the main thread-group
This hangs inside a paint operation, trying to perform a getRowColor() operation to prepare a renderer for a table cell.  As it's painting, it has the component tree-lock.

I have AWT-EventQueue-1 of the javawsSecurityThreadGroup which seems harmless enough, it looks like it might be uninvilved in the hangs, but it does get hung up on an invalidate() call for a text component (Java console?)

Lastly, I have AWT-EventQueue-2, of the javawsApplicationThreadGroup.
This particular component obtains a write-lock for purpose of setting the table data (which blocks reads against row color).  This then stalls on an update of the focused cell, which flows down scrollRectToVisible(), validateView(), updateCursor(), findComponentAt(), which needs the tree-lock held by the paint operation underway on AWT-EventQueue-0

The read-lock/write-lock is our code, and exists to let programmers worry less about threading.  I'm not prepared to axe it just because the application decides it needs extra event threads to run in parallel.

Ultimately, I want our application using a single AWT-EventThread.  Is there a way to get one of the event thread to farm requests off to the other?  Or to select which event thread is used for painting, or used when an invokeLater()/invokeAndWait() happens?

I'm not sure if it matters, but we do make use of FX in our application.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the scope of the critical sections guarded by your write locks to only writing to memory.

If you push from the critical section the subsequent notifications to update the UI, which depend on the write but are not part of the critical section for the write, and allow them to use the read lock via other control paths, your deadlock issues should resolve.

Another option may be to fork your write tasks to background threads (maintaining proper synchronization; see also [java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)) and then send notifications when writes are complete that can be executed asynchronously in the display thread.

Comment: While all good suggestions, they miss the root issue here.  Sure, I can fix this up to work properly, but for weeks of work that would fix one method call.  The root of the problem is the multiple event threads rendering 'threadsafe' code unsafe.  I'd really like to understand why there are multiple event threads, and how to get back to a single event thread.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this figured out to a fair-thee-well yet, but I think I've got enough for anyone to chase it back to a final solution.  I'll note, evidently my environment is in some way unique to Macintosh computers, as I'm not the first person looking at this problem on a Macintosh system, and I've never before encountered this problem under a Windows setting.

Java-Webstart kicks things off.  It invokes the application main() method with a thread in the Thread Group titled javawsApplicationThreadGroup.  This puts the thread in an appropriate application context, which causes any AWT/Swing calls to be passed off to the AWT-EventQueue-2, which is in this thread group.
This includes not only invokeLater(), but repaint() calls as well.

We also start up JavaFX from this thread.  For whatever reason, it puts the JavaFX Application Thread in the "system" threadgroup.  The system threadgroup is a bit tricky, the dev tools I use (Eclipse IDE/JProfiler) don't normally show threads in this group, making it a poor choice for anything.  We will also hand off requests from FX to Swing from here using InvokeLater(), and I'm sure no shortage of repaint()s.  I've not verified this directly, but quick emperical tests suggests requests from the FX Application Thread under the "system" go to the AWT-EventQueue for the "main" threadgroup.

This at least explains what I'm looking at and gives me the tools I need to combat the problem.

First steps to resolving this:  Top of the main method, I locate the "main" threadgroup and kick off a new thread in that group to perform the actual application startup.  This causes both the FX Application Thread to spawn under the main thread group, as well as our main thread-pool.  Result, both FX and background tasks submit swing requests to the same event queue.  This doesn't quite fix everything for me (still have some business logic running from threads in the javawsApplication thread group), but I think it gives me all the tools I need to reach a solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    startFromMainThreadGroup(args);
}

private static void startFromMainThreadGroup(final String[] args)
{
    ThreadGroup tgSystem = Thread.currentThread( ).getThreadGroup( );
    ThreadGroup ptg;
    while ( (ptg = tgSystem.getParent( )) != null )
    {
        tgSystem = ptg;
    }

    ThreadGroup tgMain = null;
    ThreadGroup[] groups = new ThreadGroup[tgSystem.activeGroupCount() + 16];
    int numGroups = tgSystem.enumerate(groups);
    for(int i = 0; i < numGroups; i++)
    {
        if("main".equals(groups[i].getName()))
        {
            tgMain = groups[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if(tgMain == null)
    {
        tgMain = tgSystem; // Fallback
    }
    Runnable doRun = new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            mainImpl(args);
        }

    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(tgMain, doRun, "mainFork");
    thread.setDaemon(false); // Explicit
    thread.start();
}
```